# How do I fix my CSS issue with navigation block?

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-8

I added a new advertising block to the header visible here: https://musebycl.io/test_page. This made the navigation block move to the far right. I can't figure out why that is happening, even though these elements are supposedly in separate divs.

How do I modify the header ad or the navigation HTML/CSS to bring the navigation back to its normal position as visible on the home page (https://musebycl.io/)?

[image: screenshoot of what I wish to do]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your framework applies flex rules on the .row element that push your navigation block to the right, as it has no defined width.

Try to move your add .block-content one level up in your rows into  div.container.py-2.row

with this html it works:

```
<div class="container py-2">
  <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="block-content">
      <div
        class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <div class="region region-logo">
            <div id="block-headerad"
              class="block block-block-content block-block-content98569f6a-2644-4a93-a22a-d735717c7cda">
            </div>
            <div id="block-muse-sitebranding-3" class="block block-system block-system-branding-block">
              <a href="/" rel="home" class="site-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.musebycl.io/compact-muse-logo.png" alt="Home">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
          <div class="region region-header-primary-menu">

            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center no-gutters">

        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">

          <div class="social-menu d-flex align-items-center">
            ...
          </div>

          <div class="col-auto">

            <div id="user-action-menu" class="user-action-menu d-flex align-items-center">
              ...

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="d-lg-none">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your block-content a width.
Like:

```
.block-content{
width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is indeed moving the nav back but not fully and it wraps it up and other icon elements seem to break.

Comment: Could you bring your ad-block back, so I can see where would your ad-block (div) added?

Comment: @ivan bring your ad-block back for a moment pleae, so we can see the problem.

Comment: Here is the ad block: https://musebycl.io/test_page
Thank you!

Comment: Ok, it seems you're working with wordpress and the problem is that the Theme you are using, makes the Nav out of the (ad-block and logo).
So you have to use flex to bring the logo and the ad-block on each other

Comment: It's Drupal 8, but what do you mean it's out of the ad-block and logo? It does work on the front page https://musebycl.io/. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe it's because you don't have ad-block (where your ad comes) on your font page, and if you want this like your front page, add this code please:
#block-headerad{display:none}

Answer (score 0):

You can create external CSS like

```
#advertising-nav-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="advertising-nav-bar">
        <!--content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but it just makes the whole ad section disappear for some reason. It shows up for a flash and then goes away.